# Facebook sharing video Graph API

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, android-sharing

I'm trying to share a video url from my device to Facebook. To do so I'm using following code:

```
GraphRequest request = null;
            try {
                request = GraphRequest.newPostRequest(
                        token,
                        "/me/videos",
                        new JSONObject("{\"file_url\":\"some url\",\"description\":\"Android upload\"}"),
                        new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                                // Insert your code here
                            }
                        });
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

It is the code generated at [Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer). However, I'm getting an error:

```
{
"error": {
    "message": "There was a problem uploading your video file. Please try again.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 390,
    "error_subcode": 1363030,
    "is_transient": true,
    "error_user_title": "Video Upload Time Out",
    "error_user_msg": "Your video upload timed out before it could be completed. This is probably because of a slow network connection or because the video you're trying to upload is too large. Please try again.",
    "fbtrace_id": "AxXLWPEDSIF"
}
```

}

Android Facebook SDK: **4.28.0, 4.31.0**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out parameters should be sent directly in the query. So, working code:

```
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("file_url", uri);
    parameters.putString("description", comment);
    GraphRequest request = new GraphRequest(token, "me/videos", parameters, HttpMethod.POST, callback);
```

Decided to post this because the error message doesn't get any clue what is going wrong.

Comment: I get this message( Application does not have permission for this action ) when i use " file_url"  parameter.Do we need to get pusblish video pemission?